# Regex Expression that Matches Excel-like Reference Cells

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to make a regex that only matches on the letters between the range of A-Z (inclusive) followed by a number between 0-100 (inclusive). If there are any numbers before my regex, I do not want it to match. For example: 5A1 should not match because there is the number 5 before it, even though A1 is in the string. Likewise, I do not want it to match if there are any number values after that range such as A10000 (shouldn't match because 1000 is outside of 100).

Below demonstrates what I am trying to match on:

```
A34A1                // no match
5A1                  // no match
2.344A1              // no match
A1001                // no match
A1                   // match A1
A10                  // match A10
A100                 // match A100
SUM(A1:A2)           // match A1 and A2
SUM(A1:A2, 5A1, A3)  // match A1,A2, A3
```

I have been trying these regex expressions but am unsure of how to exclude any numbers before or after that range:

```
/[A-Z]{1,2}[1-9]{0,3}/g

/([^0-9])[A-Z]{1,2}[0-9]{1,3}/g
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this regex:

```
/\b[A-Z]([0-9]{1,2}|100)\b/
```

or simpler equivalent:

```
/\b[A-Z]([0-9][0-9]?|100)\b/
```

or the shorter digit metacharacter equivalent:

```
/\b[A-Z](\d\d?|100)\b/
```

Using the `\b` metacharacter at the start and end of the regex, you eliminate any undesirable preceding or trailing characters.  The `[A-Z]` character class includes only a single uppercase letter to start the cell reference.  The numeric portion is handled by alternation of either `0-99` or `100`, where the `0-99` portion is handled by one to two digit character classes.  In place of the explicit `[0-9]` character classes, the \d metacharacter would work just as well, if that's your preference.

Here's a sample Ruby program (similar regex flavor to Javascript) to show it working:

```
data = [
  [ "A34A1",   false ],
  [ "5A1",     false ],
  [ "2.344A1", false ],
  [ "A1001",   false ],
  [ "A1",      true ],
  [ "A10",     true ],
  [ "A100",    true ],
  [ "SUM(A1:A2)", true ],
  [ "SUM(A1:A2, 5A1, A3)", true ]
]

data.each do |pair|
  puts "#{pair[1] == !(pair[0] =~ /\b[A-Z]([0-9]{1,2}|100)\b/).nil? ? 'Pass' : 'Fail'}: '#{pair[0]}'"
end
```

In the `data` array, the second element of each pair is a boolean, which determines whether the test cell reference should match or not.

The output of running this program shows all tests pass:

```
> ruby regex_test.rb
Pass: 'A34A1'
Pass: '5A1'
Pass: '2.344A1'
Pass: 'A1001'
Pass: 'A1'
Pass: 'A10'
Pass: 'A100'
Pass: 'SUM(A1:A2)'
Pass: 'SUM(A1:A2, 5A1, A3)'
```

Comment: For `r = /\b[A-Z]([0-9]{1,2}|100)\b/`,  `"A34A".scan(r) #=> []`, `"_A1".scan(r) #=> []` and `"A1_".scan(r) #=> []`, all of which are incorrect. I just read your bio. Welcome to the Ancient Rubiests Club.

Answer (score 2):

Here you go:

```
(?:^|[^0-9])([A-Z](?:100|[0-9][0-9]?))(?=$|[^0-9A-Z])
```

`$1` will hold your match.

Example usage:

```
var re = /(?:^|[^0-9])([A-Z](?:100|[0-9][0-9]?))(?=$|[^0-9A-Z])/gim;
```

## Explanation

It must be either the start of a line, or not a digit:

```
(?:^|[^0-9])
```

Then, you have one or two letters followed by either 100 or a one or two digit number:

```
([A-Z](?:100|[0-9]?[0-9]))
```

Then it must be either *the end of the line for you* or something that's not a letter/number:

```
(?=$|[^0-9A-Z])
```

Comment: Thanks but this doens't seem to work on the last 2 examples?

Comment: The OP's spec doesn't require two letters.

Comment: @AlphaWolf Fixed it. I was one character off.

Answer (score 2):

```
var regEx = "/([A-Z](\d{1,2}(?!\d)|100))|(SUM\([A-Z](\d{1,2}(?!\d)|100)((:|,)\s?\d{0,}[A-Z](\d{1,2}(?!\d)|100))*\))/g";
```

**Matches A1, A2, Z100
But not A101 or A1000**

```
([A-Z](\d{1,2}(?!\d)|100))
```

- Note: without `(?!\d)`, "A1000" will be recognized as "A100"

**Start with SUM( and end with )**

```
SUM(.*)
```

**Can have any number sets of ":" or "," follow by optional whitespace and optional number**
Matches SUM(A1:A2, 5A1, A3)

```
(:|,)\s?\d{0,}
```

Answer (score 1):

This should not be more complicated than

```
/^[A-Z](\d\d?|100)$/
```

Answer (score 1):

```
r = /
    (?<!\d)   # match a digit in a negative lookbehind
    [A-Z]     # match a capital leter
    (?:       # start a non-capture group
      \d{1,2} # match one or two digits
      |       # or
      100     # match string
    )         # end non-capture group
    (?!\d)    # match a non-digit in a negative lookahead
    /x        # free-spacing regex definition mode
```

which is commonly written:

```
r = /(?<!\d)[A-Z](?:\d{1,2}|100)(?!\d)/

test = ["A34A1", "5A1", "2.344A1", "A1001", "A1", "A10", "A100",
        "SUM(A1:A2, 5A1, A3)", "A100A", "_A1", "A1_"] 

test.each { |s| puts "#{s} -> #{s.scan(r)}" }
A34A1               -> ["A34"]
5A1                 -> []
2.344A1             -> []
A1001               -> []
A1                  -> ["A1"]
A10                 -> ["A10"]
A100                -> ["A100"]
SUM(A1:A2, 5A1, A3) -> ["A1", "A2", "A3"]
A100A               -> ["A100"]
_A1                 -> ["A1"]
A1_                 -> ["A1"]
```